# Finding out the percentage points.( F - Distribution).

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How to find the values of these $x_1$ and $x_2$ , given ,

$P(x_1<F_{7,7}<x_2) = 0.90$ , using the F-Distribution tables..

Can anyone provide me a hint for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of $1/F_{n,m}$ is the same as the distribution of $F_{m,n}$ (with the roles of $n$ and $m$ interchanged). The reason why that happens isn't hard to see.  In this case $m$ is the same as $n$, so the distribution of $F_{7,7}$ is the same as the distribution of its reciprocal.  Thus if you find
$$
\Pr(F_{7,7}\le x_2) = 0.05
$$
then you can conclude that
$$
\Pr\left( \frac 1 {F_{7,7}} \ge \frac 1 {x_2} \right) = 0.05
$$
and since the distribution of $1/F_{7,7}$ is the same as the distribution of $F_{7,7}$ you have
$$
\Pr\left( \frac 1 {x_2} \le F_{7,7} \right) =0.05.
$$
Hence setting $x_1 = 1/x_2$ gives you $5\%$ in the lower tail and $5\%$ in the upper tail and $90\%$ in the middle.